# ffmpeg: create .mp4 from .mp3 and .jpg

Tags: image, ffmpeg, mp3

I've searched for the best way to do this and nothing seems to work. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

ffmpeg -version:

> ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
> built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
> configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
> libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
> libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
> libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
> libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
> libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
> libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
> libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
> libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
> libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100

This is the command that I'm using:

ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loop 1 -i test.jpg -i test.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4

The result won't play in VLC. And it takes a very long time for the command to finish. Also the test.jpg image had an odd number y dimension, so I made it even with imagick by reducing that size by 1.

How do you do this 'correctly'?

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Showing the complete log will allow us to give you an answer to do this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert image to correct pixel format, png is the best:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.jpg -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -preset slow test.png
```

Final, create video from png image and mp3:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i test.png -i music.mp3 -shortest -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 5M -preset slow video.mp4
```

Comment: 1) No need to convert a jpg to png to make a video from an image. 2) PNG ignores `-qmin` & `-qmax`. 3) `-preset` is not a generic option usable by all encoders. It is ignored by the PNG encoder. It is used by a few video encoders such as libx264, libx265, libaom-av1, libxavs, and libvpx.

Comment: What I found is that .jpg files work, but it takes twice as long than a .png file takes. The jpg ran at 1.77x and the png ran at about 3.55x.

Comment: Yes, .jpg is not correct pixel format - so we need to convert .jpg to .png first.